# How to initialize two dimensional array in java 8

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

Before Java 8 versions, we can initialize a two-dimensional array using for loop like below. How can I do the below in JDK 1.8 using lambda expressions?

```
int[][] board = new int[3][3];
int v = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

        board[i][j] = v;
        v++;
        System.out.println(v);
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(board));
```

Basically, I am looking for an array like below

```
[[1,6],[2,7],[3,8],[4,9]]
```

Comment: `int[][] board = IntStream.range(0, 3).mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, 3).map(j -> i * 3 + j + 1).toArray()).toArray(int[][]::new);`

Comment: Thanks @shmosel, I would like to have an array like below [[1,6],[2,7],[3,8],[4,9]]

Comment: Traditional `for` loop has better readability and better efficiency especially when handling primitive types. I would recommend using traditional `for` loop unless you are required otherwise.

Comment: is `5` intentionally missing or just forgotten?

Comment: Your loop doesn't produce that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I highly recommend you stick with using the `for-loop` for initialization of arrays with primitive values. My recommendation is stronger in the case of a multidimensional array.

However, here is the way:

```
int a = 4;               // Number of outer array elements
int b = 2;               // Number of inner array elements

int[][] board = IntStream
    .range(0, a)                                               // iterate 0..3
    .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, b)                       // for each iteratoe 0..1
                            .map(j -> 1 + (i + (a + 1) * j))   // calculate the value
                            .toArray())                        // compose the inner array
    .toArray(int[][]::new);                                    // compose the outer array
```

Note that the [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) is able to create an array of primitives since it is a sequence of primitive int-valued elements. its method [`IntStream::toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#toArray--) reutrns `int[]`.

The composition of the outer array is a bit tricky since `int[]` is no longer a primitive value but an array itself. There is needed to use a method [`IntStream::mapToObj`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-) which maps `int` to an object - then the [`Stream<int[]>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) is returned and the method [`Stream::toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-) converting to array with parameter has to be used since you cannot convert `Object[]` to `int[][]`.

The parameter passed is simple. `int[][]::new` is nothing different than `i -> new int[a][b]`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `IntStream`. This will create a continuous stream of integers from `0` inclusive to `n` exclusive. So for a 3 x 3 matrix, the `IntStream` is `0, 1, 2`. 
make another `IntStream` for each integer in the outer stream from `0` to number of columns - also 3.

You cannot increment `v` in a stream because it must be "effectively final". Instead we use the equation `board[j][i] = 1 + (j + m * i)` which is effectively the similar to computing the index of the value if you were to flatten board into a single array (1D matrix).

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

class J {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n = 4;
    int m = 2;

    // n x m matrix
    int[][] board = new int[n][m];

    // Cols (m)
    IntStream.range(0, m).forEach( i -> {

      // Rows (n)
      IntStream.range(0, n).forEach( j -> {

        // Multiply i by row count
        // to account for the row we are in
        board[j][i] = 1 + (j + n * i);
      });


    });

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(board));

  }

}
```

Output:

```
[[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8]]
```

**Note:** Just because streams allow you to write a neater, functional programming-like syntax, there is often times an associated performance toll. It stresses the idea, "why fix what's not broken?". For a 3 x 3 board, you probably won't see a difference. But, if your board were a lot larger, it probably won't prove itself to be worth it, considering all the objects created and extra space used behind the scene. Sometimes a simple for-loop (especially when working with arrays) is better.

Remember, simplicity is key.

Comment: Thanks. I want like  [[1,6],[2,7],[3,8],[4,9]]

Comment: @sc1234 What about 5? You skipped 5 in your sequence. You need to make the matrix `4 x 2` (4 rows each of which with 2 columns) You specified the board to be `3 x 3`. Meaning you have 3 rows, 3 columns. Your expected output is not consistent with the input you supplied us to work with.

Comment: @sc1234 Edits made

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the `IntStream` methods `range` and `iterate`:

```
int width = 4, height = 2;

IntStream.rangeClosed(1, width)
         .mapToObj(column -> IntStream.iterate(column, v -> v + width)
                                      .limit(height)
                                      .toArray())
         .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

By using `iterate` for the inner loop and `rangeClosed(1, width)` instead of `range(0, width)` we can simplify the calcuation a bit. Using `toArray`  removes the need to create and modify the array yourself and would enable parallel processing.

It is important to actually use streams properly to make them more than just weird looking for loops. Merely replacing your loop by a `range(0, x).forEach(...)` to modify a local variable does not really "use streams", and it is better to stick to for loops then.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stream solution that is "nested for cycles" look a like.

1. Get the sequence of the numbers from 0 to N(Upper limit exclusive -> N = board.length;
2. Get the sequence of the numbers from 0 to M(Upper limit exclusive -> M = board[i].length;
3. For each of the couples (i, j) set the value of board[i][j] using the func (i + j * step + 1) where step is defined as 5.

Output for *int[][] board = new int[4][2];*

> [[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9]]

Output for *int[][] board = new int[4][3];*

> [[1, 6, 11], [2, 7, 12], [3, 8, 13], [4, 9, 14]]

```
int step = 5;

IntStream.range(0, board.length).forEach(i ->
    IntStream.range(0, board[i].length).forEach(j ->
        board[i][j] = i + j * step + 1
    )
);
```